# Unable to create a custom header to use it in "withManager"

Tags: haskell

I can't create a custom header **without using OverloadedStrings**

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

import qualified Network.HTTP.Headers as HHeaders
import qualified Network.HTTP.Types as HTypes
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC8

-- myHeader1 = (HHeaders.HdrAccept $ C8.pack "some data")
myHeader1 = HHeaders.mkHeader HHeaders.HdrAccept "some data"

get :: String -> IO (Response LC8.ByteString)
get url1 = do
  req1 <- parseUrl url1
  res1 <- withManager $ httpLbs req1 { method = HTypes.methodGet, requestHeaders = [myHeader1] }
  return res1
```

An error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘HHeaders.Header’
                   with ‘(HTypes.HeaderName, C8.ByteString)’
    Expected type: HTypes.Header
      Actual type: HHeaders.Header
    In the expression: myHeader1
    In the ‘requestHeaders’ field of a record
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `httpLbs`? Based on the error I would guess that you need a [`HeaderName` from Types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.8.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-Header.html#t:Header) but you use the one from `Headers`

Comment: @Carsten httpLbs --> https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.2.1.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network.HTTP.Conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html) and [Network.HTTP.Headers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.0.7/docs/Network-HTTP-Headers.html) are from incompatible HTTP libraries. Request headers for `http-conduit`/`http-client` can be created using the `http-types` library:

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.HTTP.Conduit as HHeaders
import qualified Network.HTTP.Types as HTypes
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC8

myHeader1 = (HTypes.hAccept, C8.pack "some data")

get :: String -> IO (Response LC8.ByteString)
get url1 = do
  req1 <- parseUrl "some url"
  res1 <- withManager $ httpLbs req1 { method = HTypes.methodGet, requestHeaders = [myHeader1] }
  return res1
```

To clarify:

You were importing [Network.HTTP.Headers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.0.7/docs/Network-HTTP-Headers.html) from the `HTTP` library. Although the imports look similar, this is a self-contained library which defines it's own header types and not intended to be used with http-types.

`http-client` is compatible with the `http-types`. If you follow the definition for [RequestHeader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.8.6/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-Header.html#t:RequestHeaders) it will lead you to `http-types`.

In the future, one way to check the compatibility of orthogonal libraries is to look at the build depends on the Hackage index or follow the types as far as possible.

Comment: What am I using from `Network.HTTP.Conduit`? Or rather what am I using what I shouldn't be?

Comment: You are currently using `httpLbs` from `http-conduit` which is a layer over `http-client` providing streaming capabilities. You imported `Network.HTTP.Conduit` in your pasted code, not `Network.HTTP.Client`. They are effectively the same thing in this example.